# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column) doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why DISTINCT UID doesn't work in my code below?

```
$q = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UID) AS TOTAL, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN SYSTEM = 'Android' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
     SUM(CASE WHEN SYSTEM = 'IOS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS I,
     SUM(CASE WHEN SYSTEM = 'Windows' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS W FROM user_visits"));
```

The query returns all items from the database selected even I put DISTINCT UID or *. Same result.

Comment: How many duplicate UID do you have? Maybe you have no duplicates

Comment: Many! One UID per day with many days storeed.

Comment: Stop using the deprecated/removed `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (2013), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0 (2015). Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) (i.e. show some sample data and expected result). The PHP part of this is irrelevant - although you should definitely upgrade your obsolete library, as mentioned above.

Comment: I still using 5.6 as PHP version in my cPanel. I know it needs to be upgarded to 7 or above but this requires lot of code upgrades and needs time for that.

Comment: As mentioned above, it's been 7 years since PHP 7 was released...you've had plenty of time 
 already :-)

Comment: I refute the contention that count(distinct does not work - please ad  sample data which makes you think it does not.

Comment: SYSTEM is a reserved word, so you must put it in backticks or stop using  reserved words all togehter

Comment: As stated above, I'd like to know what are you expecting to get... or what you think DISTINCT does

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto total number of each case but grouped by UID (User ID). I tried with GROUP BY UID after FROM part but still not work.

Comment: @nbk i changed SYSTEM column name into SYSTEMS. nothing changed.

Comment: @Adrian this works on every mysql database https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=5849a7b58a6e7a81b42435df1edada61  , your main problems seems to be that we don't have your data, a uuid produces a unique number every time, you eneter it see example, so no wonder that you can get always teh same count. so as we don't know anything about your data every thing is speculation

Comment: @Adrian You can use mysqli and pdo on PHP 5.6, so you are creating more work for yourself later by not switching right now. Having some outdated mysql_ uses doesn't mean you have to keep using that outdated API for all new code.

Comment: @Adrian as others have stated without some sample data we can't tell what's wrong... but you are missing the GROUP BY for sure `SELECT UID, SUM(CASE {..etc...} FROM user_visits GROUP BY UID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distinct` keyword is supposed to be outside like below,

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name; 
?
```

Also, you are trying to sum few things, It should be something like below,

```
SELECT UID, COUNT(UID) AS TOTAL, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN SYSTEM = 'Android' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
     SUM(CASE WHEN SYSTEM = 'IOS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS I,
     SUM(CASE WHEN SYSTEM = 'Windows' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS W FROM user_visits
    GROUP BY UID
```

with aggregate (group by)